# Calendar reverses hour of the day in Android

Tags: android, timepicker

I have a TimePicker in which I am choosing hour and minutes. Then I set it to Calendar, like this :

```
private Calendar getCalendar() {
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, picker.getCurrentHour());
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, picker.getCurrentMinute());
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    return calendar;
}
```

The problem is that if I pick for example hour : 19 and minute 41 which is 19:41 later, when I call `getCalendar().getTimeInMillis()` it returns `1415688060910` which is `Tue Nov 11 2014 07:41:00 GMT+0100 (CET)`, so it reverses it. If I choose 7:41 it will be `Tue Nov 11 2014 19:41:00 GMT+0100 (CET)`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is your picker stuff? It is what is causing the issue.

Comment: I can change `picker.getCurrentHour()` to 19 and accordingly for minutes and it still returns wrong TimeInMillis.

Comment: Could this be a Timezone problem? You wouldn't happen to live on a Pacific Island by chance?

Comment: It was problem with Calendar.HOUR, @sberezin solution worked. I dont see the reason for -1 this question. Picker stuff wasn't needed.

Comment: It is really weird that that was the solution... not because of the 19:41 working now, but the 7:41 becoming Tue Nov 11 2014 19:41:00 GMT+0100 (CET) error doesn't seem to make sense with this. But whatever works :P

Comment: I put there constant values like `calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 19);` so I was sure that there is no problem with picker. Well, it's pretty obvious now. `HOUR` is 12-hour clock so 19 is 12 + 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try `calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, picker.getCurrentHour())`;

Comment: Docs: *`HOUR_OF_DAY` is used for the 24-hour clock*